# Action button is not showing in the notification when the application is in background

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

While sending the notification and when my application is in the foreground, i am getting the notification with the action buttons in the notification, while when my application is killed or in background the notification is coming but without the action button, i am getting just the title and content body.
I have tried many solution but it does work. Is android have new permission issues are introduced?
Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skbax.png)

Comment: What action buttons? It would be great if you would show any UI or just some part of the code.

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan i have added the image please check once.

Comment: yes i am getting these two points but the issue is when the application is in foreground it is coming with the action button while in background mode the action button is not coming.

Comment: Because onMessageReceived() is executing only when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: could you please post some lines of code regarding the Data Payload.

Comment: You need a backend side, which will write a backend code to send notifications through FCM. That will be a data payload. Or as I know you can also write your own cloud functions for this in the Firebase. That data payload you'll receive is a map. In the onMessageReceived() when you get RemoteMessage as an argument, it has getData() method which returns a map. That will be your data payload.

Comment: Thankyou so much it helped me to get this to work. But the expandable icon is not visible on notification, i don't know why it's happening. But while swipe is working with contenttext of notification is working.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you need to set some styles for notification expand? But on my phone there's no expandable icon, I expand it with a swipe.

Comment: @Abhi some issue i am facing that not expandable icon and also no action buttons.
MyFCM push notifications are arrived on on messageReceived its working fine and i am receiving payload from backend as well. when i create notification. its not showin action button when app is in background or killed.

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.triaden_notification_channel_id))
      .setContentText("$notificationText")
       .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
          .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
          .setOngoing(false)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(alarmSoundUri)
         .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan can you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As there's no any code provided I can't say what's the specific issue here, butt keep in mind. In FCM there are 2 types of notifications:

- Notification payload
- Data payload

When you send a notification from FCM, it is a notification payload. In this case if your app is killed, the notification will go directly to the system tray and will be handled by the OS. The `onMessageReceived()` won't execute.

If you send the notification from the backend side, it's a data payload. In that case the `onMessageReceived()` will be executed.

Check more here [FCM Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)